# Trigger que calcula e atualiza a idade

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Quero criar uma trigger que ao ser disparada calcule a idade do cliente em cada linha da tabela e atualiza se nescessário.

Tentei da seguinte forma:

```
create trigger Atualiza_Idade
on cliente
for insert,update,delete
as 

declare
@i int,
@dtnasc  datetime ,
@Idade int,
@Hoje DATETIME,
@Condicao int
Set @i=1
Set @Hoje=(SELECT GETDATE ( ))

while (@i<(select COUNT( *) from Cliente ))
begin
select @dtnasc=DataNasimento,@Idade=Idade from Cliente where id=@i;


set @Condicao = (SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, @dtnasc, @Hoje) / 365.25));
if (@Condicao<>(select idade from Cliente where id=@i))
update Cliente set Idade=@Condicao where id=@i;

set @i=@i+1;

end
go
```

Não funcionou.

Comment: Qual o erro ou comportamento apresentado?

Comment: Não executa o update.

Comment: Você não ta dizendo onde é para atualizar. Ta faltando a cláusula `where` no `update`, não?

Comment: @mutlei realmente isso estava faltando. mas alterei e continua da mesma forma.
Obrigado !

Comment: @Anderson Tente rodar o script sem ser na `trigger` e confirme se esta funcionando. Pode ser que não esta entrando no `if` do `update`.

Comment: @Jota Fiz isso... De fato acho que não esta entrando no if. Pois o SQLSERVER retorna:"Command(s) completed successfully." Mas nada ocorre....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não vai mesmo. Faltou o uso da tabela especial `INSERTED`, que indica justamente o conjunto de registros alterados da tabela em questão.

O que você quer na verdade é uma Stored Procedure. A trigger só é ativada quando algum registro é ativado. Neste caso, ficaria:

```
create procedure Atualiza_Idade
as 

    declare
    @i int,
    @dtnasc  datetime ,
    @Idade int,
    @Hoje DATETIME,
    @Condicao int

    SELECT @i = MIN(ID) FROM Cliente
    Set @Hoje=(SELECT GETDATE ( ))

    while (@i<(select COUNT( *) from Cliente ))
    begin
    select @dtnasc=DataNasimento,@Idade=Idade from Cliente where id=@i;

    set @Condicao = (SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, @dtnasc, @Hoje) / 365.25));
    if (@Condicao<>(select idade from Cliente where id=@i))
    update Cliente set Idade=@Condicao where id=@i;

    set @i=@i+1;

end
go
```

Comment: Perfeitamente Cigano.... Mas à ainda um detalhe que esta impedindo o funcionamento. O parâmetro .@i esta recebendo o valor 1. Mas se não existe o ID 1 não vai executar 
select .@dtnasc=DataNasimento,.@Idade=Idade from Cliente where id=.@i;.
assim sendo os parâmetros .@dtnasc e .@Idade não recebem valor.
Notei isto fazendo um debug...  ainda continuo precisando de ajuda. rsrsrss

Comment: @Anderson Então você troca por `SELECT @i = MIN(ID) FROM Cliente`. Vou atualizar a resposta.

Comment: Idade não deveria ser campo gravado e sim um campo calculado.